# usage error when creating Webapp in Azure App service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I'm currently following azure official guide on node app deployment in azure app service. [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs)

Need to create a web app for the resource group and plan given by the client with below command

```
az webapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myAppServicePlan --name <app_name>
```

But whenever I do it I get the below error.Any idea how to overcome this error. Thanks

```
usage error: --runtime | --deployment-container-image-name | --multicontainer-config-type TYPE --multicontainer-config-file FILE
```

Comment: Re-paste your link.

Comment: @GeorgeChen sorry added again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I figured that out when u create a linux runtime based plan u have to make sure

```
--runtime "node|10.10"
```

parameter is added.That did the work for me